# Is Bluetooth fast enough to transfer a stream of audio data in the form of a raw byte array between two android phones?

Tags: android, performance, audio, stream, bluetooth

So the idea is to use `AudioRecord` to get a stream of audio from the microphone and send this stream over bluetooth to another device in the form of a raw byte array, just like I get it from AudioRecord, and at the same time over bluetooth receive the stream of audio from the other device and play it with `AudioTrack`. Is Bluetooth fast enough to do this between two phones while keeping a descent audio quality? If not, is there a way to do this?

Comment: A 44.1kHz 16-bit channel uses 700kbps (which was the bandwidth of Bluetooth v1), while Bluetooth v2 supports 2Mbps. Odds are your Android phone's microphone can't sample that fast anyway.

Comment: @Gabe these are the theoretical bandwith numbers without error correction and protocol overhead. In practice it's much less than the 2.1mbit.

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck: Theoretical bandwidth is 1Mbps and 3Mbps for v1 and v2 respectively. What I listed was maximum application throughput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the quality that phone microphones record at, it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Required bandwidth is ~700 kbit/s for 44.1kHz/16bit MONO stream. Stereo stream doubles that (~1.4 kbit/s).

Comment: 700 kbit/s and 1.4mbit/s ?

Answer (score 0):

It's fast enough for your wireless cell and music headphones.  It's fast enough for audio and video streaming.